# How would I analyze the execution plan of this query? Would It help creating any indexes?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
SELECT ANO_LECTIVO,XCANDS.CURSO, MIN(MEDIA)
FROM XCANDS, XALUS
WHERE XCANDS.BI = XALUS.BI
AND XCANDS.CURSO = XALUS.CURSO -- UM ALUNO PODE SER CANDIDATAR A VARIOS CURSOS
GROUP BY ANO_LECTIVO, XCANDS.CURSO
HAVING MIN(MEDIA)>0;
```

I am selecting the lowest grade for each course in my table, being aware the student is signed up for that course. I'm having trouble finding out how I could analyze the impact of this query and how I could improve it. My tables have this parameters:

[Table Cands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tz5Ti.png)

[Table Alus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDdFg.png)

Comment: Please dont post pictures, post the actual schema definitions for these tables as text then people can play with it

Comment: [The MYSQL Manual for the EXPLAIN verb](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html)

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL, you can see the execution plan using `EXPLAIN` (or `EXPLAIN EXTENDED`).

Just add the `EXPLAIN` keyword to the beginning of your `SELECT` statement, and run it.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT ...
```

Your query might benefit from an index:

```
    ON XCNADS (ano_lectivo, curso, media, bi)
```

We'd expect with that index available, the query would make use of it, and expect the Extra column from the EXPLAIN output would show "Using index" (because that's a "covering index"), and not show "Using filesort" (because the GROUP BY can be satisfied from the index without performing a sort). We'd nedd to look at the EXPLAIN output to verify.)